# Add type ahead functionality to a asp.net dropdownlist control

Tags: asp.net

How do you add type ahead functionality to an asp.net dropdownlist control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More specifically, check out the ListSearch extender. A demo is available [here](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ListSearch/ListSearch.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

look at ajax contol toolkit at www.asp.net